# TypeError: Object #<HTMLInputElement> has no method 'each' at HTMLInputElement.n.fn.extend.val

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have used **jQuery.2.1.4** and **angular 1.2.25**.

I am using the international-phone-number
https://github.com/mareczek/international-phone-number/blob/9c41abeffcc7537b5847c1052cb1c7ae16d7fc56/releases/international-phone-number.min.js plugin for my project,all works fine in front end, but in my console i have an error in

> TypeError: Object # has no method 'each' at
>   HTMLInputElement.n.fn.extend.val(path/to/jQuery.2.1.4)

its diffcult to find that error. please help my, Thanks.

Comment: Produce your code here, and better make a JSFiddle for that ...

Comment: No one will tell you what your problem is from a minified CSS...

Comment: Hi  , I advice providing some piece of code that can let us help you , othervise you may have down votes in minutes.